# Adding File Contents to a List Does Not Work

Tags: dart

I want to add the contents of a file to a list, but somehow the list seems to not get filled. Maybe we need some asynchronous code here.

Please help!

```
class App {
  Map<String, List<Model>> models = {
    'users': List<User>(),
    'groups': List<Group>(),
    'events': List<Event>()
  };

  App() {
    loadUsers();
    print(models['users']); // prints empty list: []
  }

  void loadUsers () {
    Directory usersDirectory = Directory.fromUri(Uri(path: './app/data/users'));
    usersDirectory.list(recursive: false).listen((FileSystemEntity userFile) async {
      Map<String, dynamic> userFileContent = jsonDecode(await File(userFile.uri.path).readAsString());
      models['users'].add(User.fromJson(userFileContent));
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get directories without `listen`:

```dart
usersDirectory.listSync(recursive: false).forEach((userFile)  {
  Map<String, dynamic> userFileContent = jsonDecode(await File(userFile.uri.path).readAsStringSync());
  models['users'].add(User.fromJson(userFileContent));
);
```